# Will Fermat's last theorem hold true on the Complex Plane?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

> **Fermat's Last Theorem**
>
> In number theory, Fermat's Last Theorem (sometimes called Fermat's conjecture, especially in older texts) states that no three positive integers a, b, and c can satisfy the equation $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for any integer value of $n$ greater than two.

Now the question is will Fermat's last theorem hold true if we extend the question to the complex plane. Ie when $a$, $b$ or $c$ can be complex numbers. Why or Why not and is there any prove to it?

Answer (score 8):

Note that for any  $w\in\mathbb{C}$, with $w\not=0$, the equation $z^n=w$ has $n$ distinct complex roots. So Fermat's Last Theorem does not hold in $\mathbb{C}$. For example
$$(3+i\sqrt{7})^4 + 4^4=(1-i\sqrt{7})^4.$$
Moreover, even restricting to real numbers, we have that
$$1^n+1^n=2=(\sqrt[n]{2})^n$$
On the other hand, Fermat's Last Theorem for [Gaussian Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) is still open: see this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90972/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-mathbbz-or-i-mathb).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies. I will make it a comment.

Comment: Note that for $n=4$,
$$ 4^4 + (-3-\sqrt{-7})^4  = (1-\sqrt{-7})^4 $$
and for $n=5$,
$$ 2^5 + (-1-\sqrt{-3})^5  = (1-\sqrt{-3})^5 $$
then these solutions to $x^n+y^n = z^n$ also have $x+y = z$ and considered trivial by the "_Debarre-Klassen conjecture_", discussed in the linked 2012 MO question above.